# Подсчитать количество нажатий

Tags: swift

Добрый день помогите плиз разобраться
как посчитать количество нажатий на экран и ввести условие (если количество нажатий >20, то вывести сообщение)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вссе 20 должны быть в одной точке то:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("tap:"))
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 20
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

}

func tap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("tap")
}
```

если где угодно по экрану:

```
var numberOfTaps = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("tap:"))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

}

func tap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.numberOfTaps++

    if(self.numberOfTaps >= 20) {
        print("tap")
        self.numberOfTaps = 0
    }
}
```

Comment: хорошо! благодарствую